# Dual monitor setup only one monitor detected

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup connected through dvi-d and vga. Until yesterday everything went fine, but now both screens turn on at kernel boot, while the vga screen turns off at ubuntu 14.04 boot. At the display settings the dvi-d screen is detected as "Built-in Display", while I'm not on a laptop and the other screen isn't even detected anymore. How do I get both monitors back?